# Use Weka-generated classifier in my Android app

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, classification, weka

I was trying to follow the tutorials located [here](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture22/lecture22.html) for a simple Android activity detection app. The tutorial was very informative. In Weka, I generated a Java classifier like below:

```
class WekaClassifier {

      public static double classify(Object[] i)
        throws Exception {

        double p = Double.NaN;
        p = WekaClassifier.N36673c9f0(i);
        return p;
      }
      ......
      static double N1901b54e3(Object []i) {
        double p = Double.NaN;
        if (i[64] == null) {
          p = 2;
        } else if (((Double) i[64]).doubleValue() <= 4.573082) {
          p = 2;
        } else if (((Double) i[64]).doubleValue() > 4.573082) {
          p = 1;
        } 
        return p;
      }
    }
```

But it didn't go further how to use this generated Java code in my Android app, so I'm confused. How can I use the generated Java code? Example usage would certainly help.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the question is. You can add this class to your project. Then, if you have a `Double array[] = new Double[65];` and fill it with some values, you can call `double result = WekaClassifier.classify(array);` to obtain the classification result.

Comment: I get the general picture. The return values are confusing; these p integers are corresponding to the index of the results I guess?

Comment: I think that the returned value is just the predicted class (unless it is `NaN`). In the example, described at the site, it would roughly be `p==0`: `"standing"`, `p==1` : `"walking"` etc. (I'm not entirely sure about this, but if nobody else answers, I'd re-read the details and turn it into an answer *if* this was the actual core of the question)

Comment: Yes I think the same way. The thing is that there is no information about these mappings in the Weka generated file.

Comment: Again, take everything that I say with a *huge* grain of salt (I've only used Weka programmatically, and never used their UI or this "WekaClassifier"-Generator). But I think that the main point of this generated "WekaClassifier" is to have a file where the Classification rules are "baked" for *one* specific data set. In order to sensibly *use* it, you still have to know the structure of the data set (and thus, to which class e.g. `p=1` belongs). If you want an more generic use of the Weka classifiers, you'd have to feed the Weka classifiers with your current data, using `trainClassifier`